# What is the indirect version of this formula?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=(F1-C1)*60*24
```

How do I make this work for whatever row it is typed in by GAS.

If necessary I can do a GAS variable solution but I think there should be an indirect solution directly in the formula, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
=(indirect("F"&Row())-indirect("C"&Row()))*60*24
```

By entering this formula it will work everywhere on the sheet that I need it to.

Comment: pls add some explanation code only answers are bit confusing to others